# Hyperbola and 3 normals from point P

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

From any point P on the hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ three normals other than that at P are drawn. Find the locus of the centroid of the triangle formed by feet of the normals.

Do we actually need to find all the three feet because that seems quite a tough job. What should be the starting point for solution?

Comment: You don't need to find the 3 feets, it is easier to work out the coordinates of the centroid $(x_c,y_c)$ directly.
Let $(u,v)$ be the coordinate for the feet of one of three normals or $P$.
If you setup the equations for $(u,v)$ and then eliminate $v$, you will obtain a quartic equation in $u$, i.e. something like $$\alpha_4 u^4 + \alpha_3 u^3 + \alpha_2 u^2 + \alpha_1 u + \alpha_0 = 0$$
You can read off $x_c$ using the relation $$3x_c + x= -\frac{\alpha_3}{\alpha_4}$$
You can do similar thing to $y_c$. It turns out the final expression for $(x_c, y_c)$ is very simple in terms of $(x,y)$.

Comment: @achillehui Can you please elaborate your approach?

Comment: *three normals other than that at P are drawn* - I can only find two, one on each branch.

Comment: Hmm.. it seems the quartic equation I mentioned before always have a pair of complex roots when $y \ne 0$, this will explain Lucian's observation that he can only find one (exclude the one at $(x,y)$) instead of three normals. The original problem is probably about ellipse instead of hyperbola....